# How do I send only csv file(json) to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I am trying to upload and save the `csv` data into `mongodb` and I am able to upload the file but in the database only it shows object **id** with some binary data. My question is how to send only `csv` file data(json) in `mongodb`?

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs')
var formidable = require('formidable');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/CSVDATA';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var data;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
  res.write('File uploaded'+JSON.stringify(files));
  fs.readFile(files.filetoupload.path, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // data will contain your file contents
  data.toString()

  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

      if (err) {

       console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);

      } else {

       console.log('Connection established to', url);

       var collection = db.collection('INFORMATION');

   collection.insert({'data1':data[0],'data2':data[1]})                   

     }
    });
 });
 res.end();
});
} else {
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data" accept=".csv">');
res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
res.write('<input type="submit">');
res.write('</form>');
return res.end();
}
}).listen(8080);
```

after submit the button, I am successfully created db and collections. But I am unable to see the `csv` data.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try a csv reader.

Comment: can u give some detail @AshokKumarSahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv file is not a json, if you want to save a json in mongodb, you need to read the csv file with any library, create a json, and insert in mongodb